# MEF doesn't discover exports in assembly loaded from byte[]

Tags: c#, mef

I am trying to use MEF to help with an application that accepts plugins loaded from a database. When I try creating a new `AssemblyCatalog` and pass in my dynamically created assembly, MEF appears to be unable to discover any `Exports`.

```
Assembly a = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyMover().GetAssemblyBytes("Plugin1"));
AssemblyCatalog c = new AssemblyCatalog(a);
```

`AssemblyCatalog` doesn't contain any parts (but it should).

If I move my exportable class into the current assembly then run the following:

```
AssemblyCatalog c = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

MEF discovers the part just fine (which I would assume).

The interface is defined in a shared assembly:

```
public interface IPlugin
{
    string Name { get; }
}
```

The assembly `Plugin1` has a single class:

```
[Export(typeof(IPlugin))]
public class TestPlugin1 : IPlugin
{
    public string Name
    {
        get { return "Plugin1"; }
    }
}
```

I thought MEF used reflection to discover parts, so I verified that the assembly was loaded correctly and contained a class `TestPlugin1`.

```
foreach (Type t in a.GetTypes())
        {
            MessageBox.Show(t.Name);
        }
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: No internal Namespaces at all?

Comment: I replaced the part using AssemblyMover with a call to File.ReadAllBytes and it worked.